# Regarding Ribbon controls in delphi

Tags: delphi, ribbon-control

Hi How can i save the current state of Ribbon So that i can load ribbon with the same state while opening the exe next time using Delphi?

Comment: I think the title is bad... can you edit to put a more specific one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Windows Registry to save state of Ribbon when application closes, and then restore when opening Application.

This is code for work with Registries:

```
      function LoadStringFromRegistry(sKey, sItem,
sDefVal: string; RootKey : HKEY = HKEY_CURRENT_USER): string;
    var
      Reg : TRegistry;
    begin
      Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);  // REMOVE
      try
        Reg.RootKey := RootKey;
        if Reg.OpenKey(sKey, false) then
        begin
          Result:=Reg.ReadString(sItem);
          Reg.CloseKey;
        end
        else
          Result:='';
      finally
        Reg.Free;
      end;
    end;


    procedure SaveStringToRegistry(sKey, sItem, sVal : string; RootKey : HKEY = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
    var
      Reg: TRegistry;
    begin
      Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE);
      try
        Reg.RootKey := RootKey;
        if Reg.OpenKey(sKey, true) then
        begin
            reg.WriteString(sItem, sVal);
            Reg.CloseKey;
        end;
      finally
        reg.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

State Registry in uses list.

Sample:

```
  SaveStringToRegistry('Software\Company\Application', 'Left','20',HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
  left := LoadStringFromRegistry('Software\Company\Application', 'Left','',HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
```

If you want to save state for each individual user of Windows use HKEY_CURREN_USER instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

If your application have other way of user management (Database), save state of Ribbon in database.

Comment: -1 because the question is about ribbon, not about how to store information in the registry.  Furthermore, you recommend to store information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and you don't mention this require application elevation in modern windows, because a normal user (even an administrator) doesn't have enough rights to write to HKLM)

Answer (score 0):

I never used the standard Ribbon in Delphi.. but after my comment to @Ljubomir answer, I decided to investigate a bit to help you.

From source code, looking at the way the customize dialog works I discovered Ribbon is tied to TActionManager, which also I never used beforehand.  Again, Looking at the source of TCustomActionManager, I noticed the SaveToFile/SaveToStream LoadFromFile/LoadFromStream methods I suppose is the way to save/load the ribbon (action manager) state information.

ON the other hand, the TActionManager have a FileName property.  If you set it, it automatically loads and saves the ActionManager state at proper times.

Hope this brings light to you.